# In Eclipse Run on Server window is opening but can't do further action telling not responding

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

Im Using Eclipse Luna and i configured Apache tomcat 8 has runtime environment.

And then i selected my project and clicked run on server option

Run on server window appeared and i tried to choose server from list but loading icon appeared and telling not responding

so please give me solution

Comment: May be improper server configuration issue, Try to remove server and add new server configuration from Windows -> Preferences -> Server -> Runtime Environments.